# How to rewind Glider.js properly

Tags: javascript, slider

I am trying to make a slider that will scroll to the beginning/end when its respective endpoint is reached. But this code below is not going from the last image to the first. But it is going from the first image to last

```
<div class="glider-contain">
  <div class="glider">
    <div>your content here 1</div>
    <div>your content here 2</div>
    <div>your content here 3</div>
    <div>your content here 4</div>
  </div>

  <button aria-label="Previous" class="glider-prev">«</button>
  <button aria-label="Next" class="glider-next">»</button>
</div>

<script>
let slider = new Glider(document.querySelector('.glider'), {
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    draggable: true,
    scrollLock: true,
    rewind: true,
    arrows: {
        prev: '.glider-prev',
        next: '.glider-next'
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I put the code in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hc27a4je/9/, and it does seem to go from the last entry to the first.

Comment: @AasthaBist but if you create a HTML file in your device and try this you will see it's not working

Comment: It is working fine on local setup as well. Do you have any additonal css/configuration/nested elements that may be causing it? I am able to do the following things on the page generated by the code above:
- Go sequentially from 1 to 4, one by one
- Go back to one through right arrow on reaching four
- Go back to four through left arrow on reaching one
- Go back sequentially from 4 to 1